# Where should the illustration go on this wireframe UX wise?

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, mobile-web

I'm making a wireframe of a responsive website and the landing page will have text field and a cta beside an illustration. Like in the image.

[image]

Where should the illustration go ux wise in mobile devices without wasting real-estate? Behind the text field or above it?

Comment: Which option do you think is the better one? How about leaving the illustration off of the mobile version?

Comment: Yep, I thought so too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the nature and purpose of the illustration?  if it is unnecessary eye candy, **consider leaving it out of the design.**  Images behind form elements look tacky and cannot be appreciated because they are obscured by the form.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, additional illustration does not go with the wireframes, rather it is introduced in the visual design phase.

IF you really want illustrations to be added in the wireframes, then, it should be behind text-field, obviously not above it. In the wireframe stage, the designer mostly focuses on the interaction part or UI that is involved in user interaction.

Generally there are several types of wireframes. You can find better insights reading [this article](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/wireframe)

Comment: Images and illustrations are fine in wireframes.  The article you link to has many examples with images shown as crossed out boxes.